# Why do I get a 'Your request produced an error. [newNullResponse]' on my app's iTunes page?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

After uploading a new version of an app to ITC, I've been experiencing problems with the store link.

When I try to open the store link, I get a:

```
Your request produced an error. 
[newNullResponse]
```

The expected behaviour is for that link to show the store page, with the details of the app.

I updated the app recently, it seems to be happening ever since. Why is this happening?

Store link for the app: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hexagonal-lights-out/id831852843

EDIT 1: I tried to upload a new version of the app to see if this was some sort of ITC fluke, but the problem persists.

EDIT 2: There are a number of apple developer forum posts about this, namely:

- https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/12731
- https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/92922

None provide a solution or explanation as to why this is happening.

EDIT 3: Opening the link on an iphone works as expected, i.e. you are sent to the store page for the app. Opening it on a desktop browser doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is happening since November (2017) and all store links for iOS apps have this 'problem'. It has nothing to do with updating the app.

This is happening because the [AppStore was removed from iTunes](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208075):

> The new iTunes focuses on music, movies, TV shows, podcasts, and audiobooks. Apps for iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch are now exclusively available in the new App Store for iOS.

That means that as of now there is no longer any handoff/link/re-direct to the store if you're browsing iOS apps on a desktop browser.